# How to increase time by 1s and replace old DT_i with the new one

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to calculate the DT value from a model I set up on `Sim4Life.`
 Firstly, i'd like to say that I am a complete beginner and I am trying to understand how programming works in general.

Now, I have a `function` with some `constants` and `two variables`, the one being time `Dt` (starting from 1 sec to 900 secs) and the other being the initial `DT_i` value. 
I want to calculate the increase of temperature for every second and create a loop that replaces the `DT_i` value with the `DT_1_i` value and also calculates the increased temperature `DT_i_1`. 
The function looks like this: `DT_1_i=DT_i+Dt`.

I know it is a very simple problem but I couldn't work my way through other similar questions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what you have achieve so far in term of code

Comment: Literally nothing. I am working on a project that requires matlab, but since I have zero experience with programming I didn't accomplish much by myself. I have set the constants' values and tried some for and while commands but they were wrong.

Comment: I added some description below, check. next time, You need to at least write some code first and we can take from there

Answer (score 1):

## Temperature variation:

- You need initial temperature variation , I used `0`
- `T(i+1)` stands for Next temperature variation
- `T(i)` stands for present  temperature variation
- `i` stands for time step, `dt`

Read through comment in my code

## Time

Use `for loop` to set the time `for i = 1 : 900 %Temperature increase end`

**i =1:900 just means**

- first run use time = 1s,
- second run time = 1+1 = 2
- so on till 900

The code is as follow

```
% Initial Temperature variation is set to zero, unless you have some data
d = 1.3;
c = 3.7;
S_i = 3*10^3;

t_reg = 900;
%Time
t = 1:900;
% Length oftime to help me know the size of the variable needed to
% initialize
l = length(t);
% Initialize variable that used to store DT  it helps speed up
% comutation
% Initial Temperature variation is set to zero, unless you have some data
DT = zeros(1, l);


for i = 1:900
    % the value of i represent dt, first run i = 1, dt = 1, second run           
    % i = 2 and dt = 2 so on 
    if i == 900
         %do nothing already reached the last index 900, i+1 = 901 will be
         %out of range
    else 
         DT(i+1) = DT(i) + (i./t_reg).*(d.*sqrt(c*S_i)-DT(i+1));
    end
   
    
end
```

Comment: Well I didn't know I shouldn't comment in the answer section, but it makes total sense. Now the code is exactly what I needed, thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Alright just upvote my answer as accepted. You may need time to learn how stack overflow works. Welcome to the communauty!